Dapper returning zero GUID
Dapper constantly returns the default value instead of the ID. What could be the problem and how to fix it? (Dapper + PostgreSQL)
Can you explain to me what is the problem?

public async Task<Appointment?> GetByIdWithPatientAndDoctorAsync(Guid id)
{
    await using var connection = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionString);
    await connection.OpenAsync();
    const string query = """
                             select a.*, 
                                    p.*, 
                                    d.*, 
                                    c.*, 
                                    s.name as specializationname
                             from 
                                 appointments a
                             inner join 
                                 patients p on a.patientid = p.id
                             inner join 
                                 doctors d on a.doctorid = d.id
                             inner join 
                                 clinics c on a.clinicid = c.id
                             inner join 
                                 specializations s on d.specializationid = s.id
                             where 
                                 a.id = @Id
                         """;

    var appointments = await connection.QueryAsync<Appointment, Patient, Doctor, Clinic, Specialization, Appointment>(
        query,
        (appointment, patient, doctor, clinic, specialization) =>
        {
            appointment.Patient = patient;
            doctor.Specialization = specialization;
            appointment.Doctor = doctor;
            appointment.Clinic = clinic;
            return appointment;
        },
        new { Id = id },
        splitOn: "id, id, id, specializationname");

    return appointments.FirstOrDefault();
}

public class Appointment : Entity
{
    public Appointment() {}
    public Appointment(DateTime date, Guid patientId, Guid doctorId, Guid clinicId, AppointmentStatus appointmentStatus)
    {
        Date = date;
        PatientId = patientId;
        DoctorId = doctorId;
        ClinicId = clinicId;
        AppointmentStatus = appointmentStatus;
    }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public Guid PatientId { get; set; }
    public Patient Patient { get; set; }
    public Guid DoctorId { get; set; }
    public Doctor Doctor { get; set; }
    public Guid ClinicId { get; set; }
    public Clinic Clinic { get; set; }
    public AppointmentStatus AppointmentStatus { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Entity
{
    protected Entity() {}

    protected Entity(Guid id)
    {
        Id = id;
    }
    
    public Guid Id { get; }
}

I've already tried playing with splitOn and leading through as ID to another name and nothing helped.

I doubt your Entity class is compilable. You are assigning the Id value in constructor but your Id property doesn't have setter.

Is dapper always use only setters?

i understand thanks, i thought that dapper can use constructors

Dapper can use constructor, but the problem is that I don't see any of your code in the constructor with parameter that calling the base constructor and assign value for Id. Besides, as you are using parameterless constructor in the Appointment class, by default Dapper will use the parameterless constructor to bind value to the instance.

You can use constructor with parameters, but it will be difficult as you need to make sure that your constructor parameters are matched in name, sequence as the columns returned from your query. Note that your query returns all the columns from the tables, so you will have multiple Id columns from different tables. This will be complex when you try to implement the (parameters) constructor, you can't have the same variable name. Unless in your query, you explicitly set the unique column name (Example: ClinicId), instead of Id. Thus, your query should return the needed columns only.

Dapper van use private set or init, if you don't want the settee to be public

As mentioned in the comment, in the Entity class the Id property doesn't contain a setter. Thus it is not assigned with value, as default it is Guid.Empty.
Add setter should resolve the problem.
public abstract class Entity
{
    protected Entity() {}

    protected Entity(Guid id)
    {
        Id = id;
    }
    
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}

